# Find and Replace "Favourites" in Eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I use the Eclipse CDT for C development and I automate many mundance tasks using regexes. I have built up a set of quite complicated regexes that I use a lot which I have ended up keeping in a text file. Every time I want to use one of my commonly used regexes I have to copy the find and replace expressions into the find/replace dialog fields (separately) before using it. This can be very time consuming. Does anyone know of a plugin which would allow me to store and select from named fjnd/replace favourites that I can then apply to code in the editor?

Comment: If you can't find anything - I still have an old plug-in on the attic. It was actually copied from the usual text search and I added a checkbox "whole word" to it because that made searching for a special word easier. It was a bit of a hack because there is no real support to build own text search pages in eclipse. And it still works in 4.2. Shouldn't be a big deal to add a combobox. If you or someone is interested in helping to implement it, I can add it to github.

Comment: btw. this is the [plug-in in action](http://www.jaylib.org/eclipse/plugins/linesearch/linesearch.png)

Answer (score 0):

The "Find" and "Replace" dialogs have a **memory**. If you use a regex, it is saved in this memory and you can select it later using the drop-down menu in each of "Find" and "Replace".

Besides from this, I don't think there's a plugin to do what you want to do...

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the memory in the dropdowns is useful, but it only has a history of 10. So I end up copy-pasting into them quite a lot. Also, I usually use a pair of search/replace regexes so one way to select them both in one go would be good. Attaching a name to such a pair would be even better because it's often difficult to figure out which is which, especially if they are long (which mine often are). It looks like I have a plugin to write... Any idea whether there is a relevant extension point?

Comment: @PMendham No, I'm not really familiar with development of Eclipse plugins :)